# Are Port Numbers Strictly Attached to the Protocol?

Tags: security

I was playing around with hosting a local webserver, and decided to host it on port 53 as an experiment. Turns out I was able to make an HTTP GET request to localhost:53 without any issues (using Postman - chrome gives me an unsafe port error).

Is there anything preventing me from using the HTTPS protocol on port 53? I'm thinking of a case where an internal network might have rules that whitelist specific websites that are known to be safe, but may allow all outbound traffic on port 53 (for DNS). I'm not sure if this is a common firewall setup, but just as an example.

In that case, could I simply host my malicious webserver on port 53 and access it using HTTPS or am I forced to use port 443? Is there anything that prevents this technically (or any other protocol on any other port)? Are there other implications?

Comment: If you host a web site using TCP port 53, the users will need to specify port 53 in the URI, otherwise the browser will assume port 80 (HTTP) or port 443 (HTTPS), and not try to connect to port 53. See [this answer](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/a/63619/8499) for more information about port numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there anything preventing me from using the HTTPS protocol on port 53?

No, there's no network police - you can run any protocol using TCP on any TCP port you like (or UDP respectively). Using well-known ports generally simplifies life though.

As you've pointed out, using a non-standard port may cause problems when e.g. an HTTP server runs on some port other than 80 and a firewall or ACL allows port 80 only. Also, it may be awkward for users being required to specify the port in the URL or protocol configuration.